# How to decode base64 file path string in to apple script?

Tags: macos, terminal, apple-push-notifications, applescript

I am writing an apple script which will take base64 string as argument. The base64 argument is file path. I have to open this file in specific application. 
I need to decode this input argument to open the file.

I tried the following code but the **path separator (/) are decoded as %2F**.

```
set decodedFilePath to base64decode(filePath)

on base64decode(str)
    return do shell script "openssl enc -base64 -d <<END_OF_TEXT" & str & "END_OF_TEXT"
end base64decode
```

**How can I decode the base64 file path string into AppleScript which will decode the file separator also?**

Comment: If you're getting "%2F" instead of "/", that means that they're [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) *and then* base64-encoded. To decode it, you need to reverse both layers of encoding (in reverse order).

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific need to use `openssl` why not just use `base64` instead?

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* decrypts a `base64` encoded file pathname for e.g. `/Temp/base64.pdf`, a PDF doc of the manual page for `base64`.

```
set filePath to "L1RlbXAvYmFzZTY0LnBkZgo="

set decodedFilePath to base64decode(filePath)

on base64decode(str)
    return do shell script "base64 -D <<<" & quoted form of str
end base64decode
```

This also works with:

```
return do shell script "openssl enc -base64 -d <<<" & quoted form of str
```